# About "send may not send" statement in the docs

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock

I found the following phrase in the [`send` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149.aspx) documentation on MSDN:

> The successful completion of a send function does not indicate that
>   the data was successfully delivered and received to the recipient.
>   This function only indicates the data was successfully sent

What does it actually mean? Is it just says that it's unknown for the sender whether this data was read on the receiver's side via `recv` call or not?

Comment: The call to `send` returns, as soon as the payload has been copied to the driver's buffer. It does not wait for the data to go through the network stack, or the transport to complete, or the receiver to signal that it received the data.

Comment: @IInspectable It returns when the data has been copied to the socket send buffer, not the driver's buffer.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks for the correction. Although I should have been more careful in explaining, it does not make a difference in the context of the question: `send` does not report whether the data was sent or received.